# passing awk(printf) in execvp

Tags: c, linux

```
char* cmd[] = { "awk", "{ printf "%-10s %10s %10s %2s %2s \t%s \n", $3,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9 }", NULL};
execvp(cmd[0], cmd);
perror("execvp of awk failed");
```

I am using pipes for my program. I want to execute this command in C using `execvp`:

```
ls -l | awk '{ printf "%-10s %10s %10s %2s %2s \t%s \n", $3, $5,$6,$7,$8,$9 }'
```

The problem is I couldn't find the proper syntax for `printf` in this case.

Can anyone point out what's my mistake?

Comment: First of all, at least make this compile by escaping the quotation marks in the string literal.

Comment: First you might consider escaping the double quotes within the printf statement.

Comment: You might want to consider passing `cmd` instead of `prog2` to the `execvp()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape all of the backslashes and double quotes in the command:

```
char* cmd[] = { 
    "awk",
    "{ printf \"%-10s %10s %10s %2s %2s \\t%s \\n\", $3, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9 }",
    NULL
};
```

Comment: Make sure to click the check mark on my answer if it solved your problem.